# democratizing recruiting or democratizing recruitment?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, word-choice, american-english

I am trying to decide which slogan to go for?

> democratizing recruiting

or

> democratizing recruitment?

Which one makes more sense both grammatically, and logically.

**My subtitle is the following:**

> A platform that empowers its users to provide hiring recommendations

Essentially i am trying to make slogan so simple that a 5 year old can get it

Comment: If you're serious about the 5-year-old thing, then I'd recommend going with something different altogether.  They both seem cumbersome to me.

Comment: thanks im quite serious about the 5 year old thing. for many English is not their first language.

Comment: any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recruiting is what a recruiter does (an action), while recruitment is the process or result.

-ing (http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/-ing)

-ment (http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/-ment)

To be more specific democratizing recruiting would suggest that you are making the actions of the recruiter democratic while democratizing recruitment implies that you are making the process of recruitment democratic. Considering just the subtitle: *A platform that empowers its users to provide hiring recommendations*, you should go with the -ment form, as in this case (with the limited information provided), the *platform* is the process. However, if you mean to make the individual actions of the recruiters democratic and not necessarily the process as a whole, then the -ing form is what you are looking for. Considering the logical aspect of what you present, what you seem to be endorsing is the process of recruitment, so **democratizing recruitment** is the most logical and grammatically correct choice.

Comment: thanks for that. It definetly make sense. Just one quick suggestion would there be a way to rephrase democratizing recruitment to a sentence where even a 5 year old could understand?

Comment: make hiring fair?

Comment: could you elaborate on that brian?